# disable condition in rangepicker in antd design

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to disable the dates in range picker

- For start date all the previous date should be disabled and start date should be selectable only between two months , after 2 months all the dates should be disabled .
- For End date disabled all the days except the last date of months.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean the MUI range picker? A minimum working example of your code in Codepen or jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: No in antd design

Comment: Ok. My bad I missed that in the title. Can you provide a minimum reproducible example of the code?

Comment: Refer this https://ant.design/components/date-picker#components-date-picker-demo-disabled-date

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.